# Echo variable once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i display variable only once in the table.

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM babydata");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 72; $i++) {
        if ($i == $weeknumber) {
            echo "<tr><td width='40'>Week $i</td>";
            echo "<td width='500' >" . count($row[$menucompare]) . "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

this code display like this:

```
--------------
week4 |  1
-------------
week4 |  1
-------------
```

But i want to display weeknumber only once and `count($row[$menucompare])` will be counted 2 in week 4 . not 1 and 1 .

Like this:

```
--------------
week4 | 2
---------------
```

Comment: there are only 52 weeks in a year? isnt it?

Comment: how can it echo twice??? condition never satisfies

Comment: It would help if you could provide the values in your array.

Comment: added sql and it never mutter about how many weeks koz i want more then 1 year

Comment: Why not add a `GROUP BY` to your SQL statement?

Comment: The `for`-loop is actually unnecessary. From the numbers `1-72` you are only using `$weeknumber`. Just replace `echo "<tr><td width='40'>Week $weeknumber</td>" ;`. The counting should be done in your query using some kind of `GROUP BY`-statement. The `count`-statement in your PHP will always output `1` because `$row[$menucompare]` will always be a string, if the column exists.

Comment: $i =$weeknumber its the same if i put $i or $weeknumber

Comment: I meant that you also remove the `for`-loop. See my answer below. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: hi basti , i have removed the loop , and make this code 
echo "<tr><td width='40'>Week $weeknumber</td>" ;

echo "<td width='500' ><?php ?>".count($row[$menucompare])."</td></tr>"; but the result its the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to output the amount of tuples in babydata for a certain week. You can just filter out any tuples which dont belohnt to the `$weeknumber` in your query.

```
// TODO: Assert, that $weeknumber is an integer, to not be prune to SQL injection.
$weeknumber = (int)(($currentdate - $birthday) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) + 1;

// Select the amount of tuples in babydata for the desired $weeknumber.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM babydata ".
    "WHERE week = $weeknumber");

// There is only one tuple with one column that contains the amount as number. 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Output the week and the amount of data.
echo "<tr><td width='40'>Week $weeknumber</td>" ;
echo "<td width='500' >".$row[0]."</td></tr>";
```

No need for loops.

To output all weeks and their respective amount of data:

```
// Select the amount of tuples in babydata for all weeks.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT week, count(*) FROM babydata ".
    "GROUP BY week");

// For all weeks:
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    // Output the week and the amount of data.
    echo "<tr><td width='40'>Week ".$row[0]."</td>" ;
    echo "<td width='500' >".$row[1]."</td></tr>";
}
```

This assumes that you have a column `week` in your table `babydata` that contains just a number. This outputs only weeks, that have at least one tuple.

Comment: no not like that , the weeks are variable , it can be 4 it can be what ever . its about the date birth will be accounted the number of weeks.

Comment: Do you mean that `$weeknumber` can change during your loop? You can set `$weeknumber` to anything you like in the first example.

Comment: Then please modify your question. This feature is not present in your code example.

Comment: u see well my question and weeks can change depends on the date.

Comment: It seems that my debug assignment for the variable `$weeknumber` is confusing you. I removed it. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: I think I begin to understand your goal here. Could you please add the table structure for the table `babydata` to your question? Do you set $weeknumber with a value in $row?

Comment: this is my variables  $weeknumber = (int)(($currentdate - $birthday) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) + 1 ;    in the table of babydata i have only dates and the id .

Answer (score 2):

You can do that directly in the SQL. Warning: I didn't actually tested this.

```
SELECT week, count(week) FROM babydata GROUP BY week;
```

This will directly return a result like

```
--------------
week4 | 2
week5 | 3
--------------
```

Just replace `week` with the actual name of your week field, and adapt the PHP to handle the new result structure. Something along these lines:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM babydata");    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<tr><td width='40'>Week ".$row[0]."</td>" ;
    echo "<td width='500' >".$row[1]."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: you mean i will create one row of weeks ??

Comment: @user1291295, isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: i dont need to create week row in mysql and everytime count weeks there :(

Comment: You will in any case need to know which of `babydata`'s tuples belong to which `$weeknumber`.

Comment: $weeknumber i count the week number by php . i have give you the variable in comments up. the table is only dates there no weeks .